# How do I find the location of an executable in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003

I remembered that I used a tool called as `where` to find locations for any executable programs like this in a console:

```
 C:\Tmp\Where myTool.exe
 C:\Program Files\MyApp\myTools.exe
 ....
```

Now I cannot find this tool. Not sure if Windows has a build-in tool to do that search?

Comment: Various answers over on [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on windows? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows)

Comment: IF the application is running & you need to know its location, use Process Explorer( from Sys Internals).

Comment: `where` worked for me on Windows 7 Enterprise

Answer (score 651):

According to the Stack Overflow answer at [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows), `where.exe` does this on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003 and later:

#### Example

```
C:\> where ping
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE
```

In PowerShell use `where.exe`, `Get-Command` (or its abbreviation `gcm`), as `where` is the default alias for `Where-Object`.

Comment: This should be makred as the correct answer as it works without installing extra software

Comment: An important part of this answer is that in powershell, `where` is a default alias for the `Where-Object`, so you instead need to use `where.exe`, or `gcm`/`Get-Command`

Comment: What about powershell. How can I achieve the same in powershell?

Comment: @krv As @DaveAndersen mentioned, in powershell you can type `Get-Command ping` (or just `gcm ping`), which will give you full path, along with some other info.

Comment: @Sam for some reason the answer didn't work but yours did.

Comment: I have included information from @DaveAndersen in the answer - thanks.

Comment: @stevec please read the above comment: in PowerShell you must use `where.exe` instead of `where`

Comment: Sometimes this solution is not working. I have a strange annoying example: https://pasteboard.co/Jp1GQjr.png

Comment: Thanks, I was typing `where` on visual studio's shell and getting empty response whereas `where.exe` did the job. I didn't know about the alias to `where-object`!

Answer (score 38):

For me, what worked was

```
Get-Command chromedriver
```

which returns something like

```
CommandType     Name                       Version    Source
-----------     ----                       -------    ------
Application     chromedriver.exe           0.0.0.0    C:\WINDOWS\chromedriver.exe
```

Simply replace `chromedriver` with the program you're looking for

Comment: good job !  where doesnt work for mthis, this works!

Comment: And "Get-Command -ShowCommandInfo" makes sure you can read the full path.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me for the executable I installed over WingetUI / Chocolatey.

Answer (score 32):

*EDIT:*  I should have added, if you can't use the WHERE command from the command prompt, check your PATH variable.  (Just use the "path" command.)  Make sure C:\Windows\System32 is in your path.  That's where "where.exe" is located.

WHERE is the command you're looking for!  WHERE is like a cross between the UNIX shell built-in "which" and the "locate" command, in that it works for both command executables and regular files.

It's also somewhat more complex than either of those two, although, in general a simple

```
WHERE <file>
```

will work.

It's different from the "locate" command in that it's not looking through the entire filesystem.  Instead, the default behavior is to look for files in two locations:

- The current directory.
- All of the directories in the PATH variable.

So, any command that you can run directly from a command prompt without specifying the directory, will be found by the WHERE command.  (Because any command like that is already in the PATH variable list.)

If you want to search **only** in the command path variable, you can use:

```
WHERE "$path:<search text>"
```

If, on the other hand, you want to find all copies of a file in a  directory tree, you can use:

```
WHERE /R <Top Level Directory> <search text>
```

Finally, WHERE will find commands and any files with an extension from the PATHEXT variable without including the extension.  All other files have to be specified either exactly or with wildcards.

Take for example the files "dxdiag.exe" and "dxdiagn.dll".  Note the following command and its output:

```
WHERE /R C:\Windows dxdiag

C:\Windows\System32\dxdiag.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxdiag.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-d..x-directxdiagnostic_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_7c8d3f96e7882ec7\dxdiag.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-d..x-directxdiagnostic_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_206ea4132f2abd91\dxdiag.exe
```

It succeeds in returning all versions of "dxdiag.exe" because ".exe" is one of the extensions in the PATHEXT variable. (Note: "WHERE dxdiag" would have worked as well, because C:\Windows\System32 is in the PATH variable.)

```
WHERE /R C:\Windows dxdiagn
```

on the other hand, fails to return any result, because ".dll" is *not* in PATHEXT.

In this case, look at the result that adding a wildcard gives us:

```
WHERE /R C:\Windows dxdiagn*

C:\Windows\System32\dxdiagn.dll
C:\Windows\System32\en-US\dxdiagn.dll.mui
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxdiagn.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US\dxdiagn.dll.mui
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-d..iagnostic.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_en-us_daccd04369b09c70\dxdiagn.dll.mui
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-d..x-directxdiagnostic_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_7c8d3f96e7882ec7\dxdiagn.dll
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-d..iagnostic.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_en-us_7eae34bfb1532b3a\dxdiagn.dll.mui
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-d..x-directxdiagnostic_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_206ea4132f2abd91\dxdiagn.dll
```

It successfully returns ***all*** versions of dxdiagn.dll.

For more information, use "WHERE /?".  Hope this helps!

Comment: `where where`
`C:\Windows\System32\where.exe` :)

Comment: @vp_arth Was just thinking exactly the same thing :)

Answer (score 16):

Note that some things might be a little different for PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\Rob.wb-devel> where ping

PS C:\Users\Rob.wb-devel> where git

PS C:\Users\Rob.wb-devel> whereis.bat git
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe

PS C:\Users\Rob.wb-devel> where.exe git
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for both cmd and PowerShell

Comment: "whereis" `whereis.bat` ???;)

Comment: For Powershell as an addition please see my comment on @john t answer.

Answer (score 16):

open `Powershell` and use `gcm` command

> `gcm [your_exe]`

## demo

[image]

Source: [Get-Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-7.1)

#### Supplement

You can also use [Select-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) <sup>alias: `select`</sup> to filter that field you are interested in.

for example:

> gcm git.exe | select Source

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks!

Comment: Can't believe I had to scroll so low to finally find a working command. The only one that can tell me where is `gdb` located. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

use `dir`:

```
cd \
dir /s /b mytool.exe
```

the `cd \` part changes you to the root of the drive, to ensure searching starts at the top of the hierarchy.

Comment: It seems like doing a command line Windows Search.

Comment: That does a recursive search of the drive and would take forever.

Comment: The only way to find executables that **AREN'T** in the PATH environment variable is to do this. He never specified his path, he said **any executable**.

Comment: it does find the executable but takes a while.

Comment: this of course only works if you know the name of the executable or at least a portion of the name

Comment: Also, there are a few protected directories that will not be searched, containing the executable. This does not preclude to be a good alternative.

Comment: An example to use on the commandline: `cmd /c "dir /s /b pdfxedit.exe"`. `/b` is: Uses bare format (no heading information or summary, only the information itself). `/s` is recursive search.

Answer (score 4):

On windows you can use the free utility [Everything search engine](http://www.voidtools.com/) to search *instantly* for any file by full or partial name (if your hard disk is formatted in ntfs).

Comment: Night and day difference between this and windows search.

Answer (score 3):

Frustrating that it's not built-in as a simple command.

However, there are several solutions, one of which is a **batch file**.

Create a batch file (which.bat) as follows:

```
@setlocal
@set P2=.;%PATH%
@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in (%~n1%%e) do @if NOT "%%~$P2:i"=="" echo %%~$P2:i
```

This looks in the local directory, will take a filename parameter with or without an extension, and return the first match from the current directory or in the PATH.

Then run it like **`which cmd.exe`** to find the cmd.exe that will execute if you type in `cmd`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Powershell, `where` is something totally different than cmd's where.

In powershell, type:

```
(Get-Command powershell.exe).Path
```

Comment: Cheers. Didn't notice the typo.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want [which](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/which.htm), the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) project has a bunch of unix utils with individual installers.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell

```
(@($env:path.split(";")) + (pwd).Path)  | where { dir $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |? Name -eq foo.exe }
```

You can easily convert this into a Cmdlet.

Another way to accomplish this, as suggested in an edit:

```
get-command notepad.exe | select Source
```

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I just have to post this Windows' one liner batch file:

```
C:>type wh.cmd
@for %%f in (%*) do for %%e in (%PATHEXT% .dll .lnk) do for %%b in (%%f%%e) do for %%d in (%PATH%) do if exist %%d\%%b echo %%d\%%b
```

A test:

```
C:>wh ssh
C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.EXE
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\\ssh.EXE
```

Not quite a one-liner if you wrap the code in `setlocal enableextensions` and `endlocal`, which are required for users who don't have the extensions enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` is great, but slow. I found querying registry to be faster, but less reliable so I combined the two ideas into a function like so:

**app_path_func.cmd:**

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2* USEBACKQ" %%N IN (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\%~1" /t REG_SZ  /v "Path"`) DO (
 IF /I "%%N" == "Path" (
  SET wherepath=%%P%~1
  GoTo Found
 )
)

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`where.exe %~1`) DO (
 SET wherepath=%%F
 GoTo Found
)

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`where.exe /R "%PROGRAMFILES%" %~1`) DO (
 SET wherepath=%%F
 GoTo Found
)

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`where.exe /R "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%" %~1`) DO (
 SET wherepath=%%F
 GoTo Found
)

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`where.exe /R "%WINDIR%" %~1`) DO (
 SET wherepath=%%F
 GoTo Found
)

:Found
SET %2=%wherepath%
:End
```

**Test:**

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

CALL "app_path_func.cmd" WINWORD.EXE PROGPATH
ECHO %PROGPATH%

PAUSE
```

**Result:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Find+Executable+via+Batch+-+Microsoft+Office+Example+-+WINWORD+-+Find+Microsoft+Office+Path

Answer (score -2):

If you just need the path to launch it, it's often better to use the start command. For example, you can use "start chrome.exe" to start Chrom{e|ium}, regardless of where it is installed.